# jest: Test suite failed to run, TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

we were using jest from unit testing in react-native. It was working well.
We just deleted npm and installed it again and then when we tried to run unit test(npm test) we are getting following error and we are not able to run test cases.

[image]

What might have went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading jest-cli version from 18 to 19 fixed the problem.

[Issue in github repo of jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3114)

Answer (score 4):

Try to re-install both jest and jest babel last versions

`npm install --save-dev jest`

`npm install --save-dev babel-jest regenerator-runtime`

And re-run the test, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

**React 17+**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.27",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.7",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

Error was on jest 27+ version but after setting to 26 it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I started with a couple of tests using only the jest, then I initialized folder with create-react-app on my another machine and restored previous tests. After that, I switched back to my current machine, did npm install and ran tests. It gave me this error, so I deleted node_modules and did npm install again. All the tests are green now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

```
Test suite failed to run, TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Similar to @Harish_N, but I was using *react-scripts*.

In my case was totally about **updating the test related dependencies** to a newer version in the **package.json**.

Answer (score 0):

If you added this line of code in

```
global.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
```

File called "shim.js" or "setupshim.js" in your "package.json":

```
"setupFiles": [
     <rootDir>/__test__/setup/shim.js 
],
```

Remove this file. This will help to remove this error in "Jest" Unit testing.

This works for me, hope this gonna work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code.

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);
```

Font: https://rishabhsrao.medium.com/mocking-and-testing-fetch-with-jest-c4d670e2e167

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the latest version of Jest when I got the same error. I eventually realized there was a circular dependency in my source code. **Resolving the circular dependency made my tests work again**.

The output was cryptic, but in hindsight the stack trace gave me the clues I needed to see that there was a circular dependency issue. The problem was happening on the `dist/index` file, then my source files, then my `src/index` file. Here is what the output looked like, for an example:

```
FAIL  src/smoke.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

  259 |   enumerable: true,
  260 |   get: function get() {
> 261 |     return _button["default"];
      |                      ^
  262 |   }
  263 | });
  264 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "Input", {

  at Object.get [as Button] (dist/index.js:261:22)
  at Object.RealButton (src/skeleton/InputSkeletons.js:45:57)
  at Object.require (src/skeleton/index.js:4:1)
  at Object.require (src/index.ts:45:1)
  at Object.require (src/setupTests.js:4:1)
```